How is 'or' used in the sentence 'alerting no one or killing no one but key targets'?
I read a sentence:

Complete all missions after the prologue, alerting no one or killing no one but key targets.

I originally thought it means that I can choose to do any
of the two things between the 'or', but people told me that actually it means that I need to do both things.
I am quite confused. I thought 'and' should be rather used in this case, if it means
that both things should be done. That is: 'alerting no one and killing no one but key targets'.
Can you tell me how is 'or' used in this sentence? I have checked a dictionary, but seems
that this usage is not listed.
The dictionary I checked: https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/or
This sentence comes from: https://www.trueachievements.com/a168819/ghost-achievement
An explanation wiki page for this sentence: https://dishonored.fandom.com/wiki/Ghost

I wouldn't expect or here.

It's not a clear sentence. I wouldn't want its author sending me on a dangerous mission with written instructions on what had to be accomplished. The only bits of clarity are 1) don't alert anyone and 2) if you do happen to kill someone they should be a key target.   That form of two negatives joined by "or" is like a "neither-nor" construction.  But it's informal and thus somewhat sloppy.

This is simply an error. It's a fairly popular error for people to make, because moving the negation around will change which word is correct. Compare: "you must not do A, and you must not do B"; versus "you must not do either of A or B". (Which would more conventionally use "neither", as in "you must do neither A nor B", which makes it a little easier to understand the negation correctly.)

The short answer is that this choice of words is probably a mistake and should be ignored. Given the general pattern of games, it's much more likely that you must meet two requirements: 1) alert no one, AND 2) kill the key targets but no one else. As written, with OR, the literal meaning is that you could satisfy the mission by choosing only one of these requirements. And since both requirements are things "not to do," this isn't even the most idiomatic way of expressing that literal meaning. Whoever told you that "it means that I need to do both things" was not focusing on the language, but rather looking past it to the most likely meaning.
Wikis are not formally proof-read by language professionals, so it shouldn't be surprising to find non-standard usages. I'm also confused because the current state of the page uses a clearer wording:

[The character] must complete all missions after the prologue, alerting/killing no one but key targets.

There might still be better choices, but this is at least clear. I didn't bother to look back through the entire history of the page, but this version seems to have been present since earlier than 2015. (There is also another version elsewhere on the page with a comma in the wrong place, "You completed all missions after the prologue, alerting/killing no one, but key targets," reinforcing the fact that you can expect minor mistakes on fandom wikis.)

They might have wanted "nor".

The way this sentence makes sense is

Complete all missions after the prologue, neither alerting anyone nor killing anyone but key targets.

Sometimes people are trying to mimic a construction they have seen in more well written language, but bungle it up because it's not a construction they normally use. Very few people actually use neither/nor any more, but it's not so unusual that they haven't heard it or seen it somewhere. That's my guess.
